# A natural isomorphism between the dual of k-th exterior power and the k-th exterior power of the dual?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms

On the wikipedia page of Exterior Algebra under the section on alternating multilinear forms, it says:

“... By the universal property of the exterior power, the space of alternating forms of degree $k$ on $V$ is naturally isomorphic with the dual vector space $\left( \Lambda^k V \right)^* $. If $V$ is finite-dimensional, then the latter is naturally isomorphic to $ \Lambda ^k \left(V^*\right) $. ...”

I understand the first part, but I don’t see how the dual space of the $k$-th exterior power of $V$ is *naturally* isomorphic to the $k$-th exterior power of the dual of $V$? I get that they have the same dimension, but what’s the specific *natural* isomorphism?

I want to know this because I don’t see how alternating multilinear forms correspond to exterior products of covectors.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Thanks very much!

Answer (score 5):

Usually the natural isomorphism is given via a perfect pairing $$\Lambda^k V^\ast \times \Lambda^k V \rightarrow k,~ (\phi_1\wedge \cdots \wedge \phi_k, v_1\wedge\cdots \wedge v_k)\mapsto \det(\phi_i(v_j))$$
which gives rise to the desired isomorphism. The naturality of this construction is easily verified.

Comment: I see. Please excuse a further question: what’s the motivation behind this pairing? Correct me if I’m wrong, but this seems to be related to the inner product on k-vectors from an inner product on V.

Comment: You are correct: Precompose the above map by $\Lambda^k (\cdot,\cdot)\times \Lambda^k \rm{id}$ where $(\cdot,\cdot)\colon V\rightarrow V^\ast$ is the isomorphism induced by the inner product, and you get the inner product of the wedge product.

Comment: As for motivation, I think it is a good idea to get a geometric intuition about this. There are ways to visualize the wedge product in low dimensions, I think you find something about this on Wikipedia.

Comment: Great! Now my question reduces to why the inner product on wedges ought to be a determinant.

Comment: @asdq How does this give rise to an isomorphism?

Comment: @user46372819 This is a perfect pairing.

Comment: (This is only true when the characteristic of the ground field exceeds $k$.)